# Error 305010:SQL_PROC_UNSUPPORTED_TYPE_CONVERSION while running SQL Insert query into Grid DB collection

Tags: griddb

I'm working on an IOT project following the GridDB Youtube page[Import Tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-0Vt5eszMM&list=PLZiizI6Euect9q64akYBkiqLMS78UTwjO&index=11). I had an error when trying to insert into the Collection deviceMaster. The error details is provided below;

> sql INSERT INTO deviceMaster
> VALUES('device3','00:0f:00:70:91:0a','Lagos','PV234','2023-08-26T00:01:39.589145+0000','vacuaam_valve');
> D20332: An unexpected error occurred while executing a SQL. :
> msg=[[305010:SQL_PROC_UNSUPPORTED_TYPE_CONVERSION] Illegal type
> conversion on updating (sql="INSERT INTO deviceMaster
> (equipmentName,equipmentID, location, serialNumber, lastInspection,
> information)
> VALUES('device3','00:0f:00:70:91:0a','Lagos','PV234','2023-08-26T00:01:39.589145+0000','vacuaam_valve')")
> (db='public') (user='admin') (appName='gs_sh')
> (clientId='f4a4e14c-6bd5-45d2-a757-5471d53ae7a7:5')
> (source={clientId=3, address=127.0.0.1:43618})
> (address=127.0.0.1:20001, partitionId=7400)]

SQL command ran:

```
sql INSERT INTO deviceMaster
VALUES('device3','00:0f:00:70:91:0a','Lagos','PV234','2023-08-26T00:01:39.589145+0000','vacuaam_valve');
```

Here is the deviceMaster schema,

```
gs[public]> showcontainer deviceMaster

- Database    : public
- Name        : deviceMaster
- Type        : COLLECTION
- Partition ID: 45
- DataAffinity: -

Columns:

No  Name                  Type            CSTR  RowKey
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0  equipmentName         STRING          NN    [RowKey]
 1  equipmentID           STRING                
 2  location              STRING                
 3  serialNumber          STRING                
 4  lastInspection        TIMESTAMP(3)          
 5  information           STRING
```

I'm unable to resolve how to insert timestamp into the deviceMaster.
I will like to get assistance on how to fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to the error. I needed to use TIMESTAMP().

Here is how the fix works;

```
sql INSERT INTO deviceMaster
VALUES('device3','00:0f:00:70:91:0a','Lagos','PV234', TIMESTAMP('2023-08-26T00:01:39.589Z'),'vacuaam_valve');
```